# data-bind foreach for an observable number

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, knockout-binding-handlers

I am trying to display stars for each item in a list

I have an interface that has the 5-star score on a video, how do I do a foreach for the count of that score? rather than creating an array for the score?

```
interface Video{
    Score: number;
}
```

```
<td>
    <span data-bind="foreach: score">
       <span class="glyphicon-star"></span>
    </span>
    <span data-bind="foreach: 5 - score">
       <span class="glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
    </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or the `Array(score)` to create an array from the score

```
Array.from({ length: score })
```

or

```
[...Array(score)]
```

(Use `score()` if it's an `observable`)

Here's a minimal snippet:

```js
const model = {
  score: 3
}

ko.applyBindings(model)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<span data-bind="foreach: Array.from({ length: score })">
   <span class="glyphicon-star">*</span>
</span>
```